# breeze.Predicate instruction valid with JavaScript but not with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, breeze

I successfully performs breeze predicates like this with Javascript:

```
var p3 =  new breeze.Predicate('items', 'any', 'serialNumber', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Contains, '12345');
```

So I search for any items where any of these items have a serial number which contains 12345.

I need to performs same kind of query on a Typescript page but I get an error in VS:

[image]

Where I click 'Go To Definition' for `Predicate`:

```
class Predicate {
    constructor (property: string, operator: string, value: any, valueIsLiteral?: boolean);
    constructor (property: string, operator: FilterQueryOpSymbol, value: any, valueIsLiteral?: boolean);
```

So it seems that the breeze type definitions (used by typescript pages) dons not include a definition for this function with these number of parameters.

This is breeze.d.ts version is 1.4

**Question**: how to get it to work with a typescript page?

PS: it works pretty well on another Javascript page so I think it should be possible to get it working on a Typescript page, isn't it?

Thanks.

Comment: you have 3 strings before the `FilterQueryOp`.

Comment: I know and this is working pretty well on a js page, not on a ts page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I missed that, but it's fixed now.  Please get the latest version of [breeze.d.ts from the Breeze github repo](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/typescript/typescript/breeze.d.ts).  I've sent a pull request to DefinitelyTyped also, but that can take a few days.

Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Thant you very much. I'll wait for the latest version to be available.

Comment: It is now updated on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/breeze/breeze.d.ts).